# Is there a way to import SSL certificate in browser using JavaScript or ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

When facing an untrusted SSL certificate, all browsers show a dialog asking you to accept or add the exception. I am interested in finding a way in Javascript or ajax to detect the untrusted SSL certificate error, then import it from url to the browser's certificate list programmatically. Is there any way ?

Comment: There might be a way to do it with a browser extension, but it would be browser-specific.

Comment: It would make SSL rather pointless if any unsecured webpage could run JS that would tell the browser to trust any certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Both sides of your question is impossible. First phase is detecting certificate status of an SSL connection (which is totally OS/Browser level task) is nothing to do with javascript. There can be third party browser extensions but again that's not the case & probably that kind of tools involves a third party tool or computer.

Second importing certificate is way impossible than the first. Any web page that can automatically install a "trusted" certificate is totally against the idea of HTTPS via SSL or TLS.